# Adding into a new column data from another table column

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert into a table column data from another table column in SQL.

For example:

```
TABLE A: ID, COD_LOC, IMP_TOT

TABLE B: ID, SUP, IMP_TOT
```

In table B I've the column IMP_TOT filled with NULL. I want to insert the data from tableA.IMP_TOT to tableB.IMP_TOT where A.ID=B.ID.

How can I do that in SQL?

thank you for time

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: you want update the column imp_tot in table B with the corresponding value in table A  .? .. which   db you are using?

Comment: I'm using Hive, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE tableB SET IMP_TOT = ( SELECT IMP_TOT FROM tableA WHERE ID = tableB.ID )
```

### Edit

```
MERGE INTO tableB USING tableA ON tabelA.ID = tableB.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET IMP_TOT = tableA.IMP_TOT
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I'm using Hive and it doesnt recognize de sentence :(